# Superset cannot connect to my Sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, apache-superset

I have a database in sqlite and followed [this tutorial](https://shuaiw.github.io/2017/08/26/building-beautiful-dashboards-with-superset.html)  on how to create it. I checked, the database exists and contains values.

I entered following SQLAlchemy URI in the web interface of the superset: `sqlite:///Users/me/Documents/cancellation/item/eventlog.db`

and got following error:

> ```
> ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!\n\nThe error message returned
> was:\n'NoneType' object has no attribute
> 'get_password_masked_url_from_uri'"}
> ```

I do not understand why there should be a password, if in the documentation there are not passwords specified:

> http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html#sqlite

Code:

```
sqlite_file = 'eventlog.db' # the DB file
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file) 
eventlog.to_sql('eventlog', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>engine = create_engine('sqlite:////Users/me/Documents/cancellation/item/eventlog.db)
```

Comment: Can you add any code for reference?

Comment: @thatrockbottomprogrammer I edited my question and added the tutorial I used to create the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue drove me crazy for the last few days.  I eventually found that you actually have to save the database config and then return to the page for the "Test Connection" to actually succeed.  Attempts to use the "Test Connection" button prior to hitting Save produce the error message that you listed.

Comment: In the end I inserted it into URI of already provided example of the database. :)

Comment: This looks like a bug. It would make sense to post an issue on github (if there is none yet).